# Requests.get() returns correct data on the first run and then returns html code

Tags: python, api, get, python-requests

So I am using the code below to get json data about my Instagram account using Python and requests library.

```
import requests

a = requests.get('https://instagram.com/asjadmurtaza/?__a=1')

print(a.text)
```

When I run it for the first time, it returns the correct output(same output as returned by chrome when we put the URL in search bar), but when I run it again, it starts returning the HTML code for Instagram login page instead of json data about my account. Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I tried it multiple times, didn't cause any problems on my end...

Comment: Same here, no issues running multiple times

Comment: can you show me your output ?